# Writing data to reserved memory

Tags: c

In linker file reserved flash  memory to store some parameter value.i reserved 512 bytes.as of now am using 200 bytes.after 200 bytes up to 512 am seeing default value FF,

If I use constant unsigned long 64 variable this value is storing from  200  to 208  memory location.

Unable to understand why compiler directly writing this value.Checking all these value in hex file.controller is stm32 L476 keil.

But in code no one is writing these values.

Comment: Why do you say "200 bytes up to 512 am seeing default value FF" and then say "I use constant unsigned long 64 variable this value is storing from 200 to 208 memory location"? It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Reserved memory 512 bytes.in that only 200 bytes are used.when I create new  constant variable.Varible value  automatically storing in region of 200- 512 byte space.

Answer (score 1):

It is flash memory (not ROM) and unitialized (erased) it has all bytes set to 0xff. You cant write it directly, you neeed to use flash memory peripheral to unlock, erase and program this memory during the program execution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But no one is writing in this memory.